# Displaying all terms of a custom taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy "people". I select the related person in each post. In  single.php file I can get the related person of a post. I can also get the list of all posts of a person through a link like www.mysite.com/people/john/

What I need now is a page that lists all "people". Is there an already implemented file for it?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a file for this.

[`get_terms( $taxonomies, $args )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

So you will need to [create your own template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Creating_a_Page_Template) then [select it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Selecting_a_Page_Template) from the list of templates in a page in.

Comment: how can I reach this page if I create a new template file?

Comment: If you created the template correctly you should be able to [select it](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/choose-custom-page-template.jpg) from the list of templates in a page.

Comment: You should add your comment through an [edit] to your answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated it.  Will be sure to do this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For a recent project, I had to do this.

Here is the code I used to gather the custom post type categories:

```
$profession_terms = get_terms( 'professions', array(
  'orderby'    => 'count',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'hide_empty' => 0
) );
foreach( $profession_terms as $term ) {
  $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
  ... do other stuff
}
```

Assuming John is a tag, the variable $term_link will grab that link so you can put it into your code.

I also had custom post type tags and this is the code that I used to retrieve those:

```
echo '<div class="states">';
  $argsState = array(
    'smallest'                  => 16,
    'largest'                   => 16,
    'unit'                      => 'px',
    'number'                    => 50,
    'format'                    => 'flat',
    'separator'                 => "&#183;",
    'orderby'                   => 'name',
    'order'                     => 'ASC',
    'exclude'                   => null,
    'include'                   => null,
    'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
    'link'                      => 'view',
    'taxonomy'                  => 'state',
    'echo'                      => true,
    'child_of'                  => null, // see Note!
);
echo '<h4 class="widget-title">Peruse by State</h4>';
wp_tag_cloud( $argsState );
echo '</div>';
```

You would, of course, have to modify this code to agree with your custom post type's tags and categories.

Here's all the code for that template:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Stories List
* Description: Displays Professions with list of stories and link to custom taxonomy archive
* Author: Marj Wyatt aka Virtually Marj
*
* Schema http://schema.org/ItemList
*/

if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url('/oops-this-content-is-members-only') );
    exit;
}
remove_action ('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop'); // Remove the standard loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'vm_stories_archive' ); // Add custom loop

function vm_stories_archive() {
    echo '<div class="cities">';
    $argsCity = array(
        'smallest'                  => 16,
        'largest'                   => 16,
        'unit'                      => 'px',
        'number'                    => 50,
        'format'                    => 'flat',
        'separator'                 => "&#183;",
        'orderby'                   => 'name',
        'order'                     => 'ASC',
        'exclude'                   => null,
        'include'                   => null,
        'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
        'link'                      => 'view',
        'taxonomy'                  => 'city',
        'echo'                      => true,
        'child_of'                  => null, // see Note!
    );
    echo '<h4 class="widget-title">Peruse by City</h4>';
    wp_tag_cloud( $argsCity );
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="states">';
    $argsState = array(
        'smallest'                  => 16,
        'largest'                   => 16,
        'unit'                      => 'px',
        'number'                    => 50,
        'format'                    => 'flat',
        'separator'                 => "&#183;",
        'orderby'                   => 'name',
        'order'                     => 'ASC',
        'exclude'                   => null,
        'include'                   => null,
        'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
        'link'                      => 'view',
        'taxonomy'                  => 'state',
        'echo'                      => true,
        'child_of'                  => null, // see Note!
    );
    echo '<h4 class="widget-title">Peruse by State</h4>';
    wp_tag_cloud( $argsState );
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '<div class="story-content" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">';
    $profession_terms = get_terms( 'professions', array(
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => 0
    ) );
    foreach( $profession_terms as $term ) {
    $count = $term->count;
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    $blogurl = get_bloginfo('url');
    // Define the query
    $args1 = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shows',
        'professions' => $term->slug
    );
    $myQuery = new WP_Query( $args1 );
    if ( $count == 1 ) {
        $label = 'Story'; }
    if (  ( $count > 1 ) || ( $count == 0 ) ) {
        $label = 'Stories';
    }
    echo '<h2 itemprop="name"><a href="' . $term_link .'">' . $term->name . '</a><span class="entry-meta"> (' . $count . ' ' . $label . ')</span></h2>';
    echo '<meta itemprop="itemListOrder" content="Unordered" />';
    if ( $count == 0 ) {
        echo '<p>No stories found.</p>';
        echo '<p class="postlist-entry-meta">Be the first to <a href="' . $blogurl . '/add-your-story/">add your <b>' . $term->name . '</b> story</a>!</p>';
    }
    while ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) : $myQuery->the_post();
        $postID = get_the_ID();
        $postDate = get_the_date('', $post->ID);
        $postTerms = wp_get_post_terms($postID, 'city', array("fields" => "all"));
        $postCity = $postTerms[0]->slug;
        $postCityName = $postTerms[0]->name;
        $cityLinkConstruct = $blogurl . '/cities/' . $postCity;
        $postCityLink = '<a href="' . $cityLinkConstruct . '">' . $postCityName . '</a>';
        $postStateTerms = wp_get_post_terms($postID, 'state', array("fields" => "all"));
        $postState = $postStateTerms[0]->slug;
        $postStateName = $postStateTerms[0]->name;
        $stateLinkConstruct = $blogurl . '/states/' . $postState;
        $postStateLink = '<a href="' . $stateLinkConstruct . '">' . $postStateName . '</a>';
        echo '<ul class="ckicon">';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo '<li itemprop="itemListElement">';
        echo '<span itemprop="url"><a href="' . get_post_permalink($postID) .'" rel="bookmark" title="' . get_the_title($postID) . '">' . get_the_title($postID) .'</a></span><br>';
        echo '<span class="entry-meta">Dateline: <span itemprop="datePublished"> ' . $postDate . '</span> <span class="middot-large">&middot</span> ' . $postCityLink . ', ' . $postStateLink . '</span>';
        //echo '<hr>';
        echo ( wpautop (the_excerpt()) );
        echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        endwhile;
        if ( $count <> 0 ) {
            echo '<p class="postlist-entry-meta">View all Stories in&nbsp;<a href="' . $term_link .'">' . $term->name . '</a>.&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' . $blogurl . '/add-your-story/">Share your <b>' . $term->name . '</b> story</a>!'; }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    echo '</div><!-- end itemscope -->';
}

genesis();
```

I should caution that, on a site with a lot of posts, the above template could process slowly on the wrong hosting service.

Hope this helps.